# Spring Data Solr phrase search and Sorting

Tags: solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I am looking for help on Spring data solr phrase search and ordering.

When I search for "Spring Data", it should return the data that has "Spring Data" in it.

```
> Ex:- Should return ---  Spring Data is good 
> Should return --- 123Spring Data123 is good 
> Should not return --- Spring and Data
```

Also, the result should be in the sorted order based on the number of fields matched.

When I get the search input from the user, I do search as below.

```
public interface SolrSecurityRepository extends
        SolrCrudRepository<SolrSecurity, String> {

    @Query(value = "subject:*?0* OR content:*?0*")
    List<SolrSecurity> find(String searchStr,
                Pageable pagebale);

}
```

Not sure how to achieve exact phrase match ....

Also, Is there anyway to enable the debug to see the query being generated by Spring data solr ...

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Solr relies on the behavior of the [Standard Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser). By default no action is performed to enforce sorting in any way, which means documents are sorted by *score*. An exact phrase search would mean you'd have to quote the terms string. You can have a look at the score assigned by adding a *readonly* score property to the entity and alter the annotated *Query* to read the given list of *fields*.

```java
class SomeDocument {
  @Id String id;
  @Indexed(readonly=true) Float score;
  // ...
}

@Query(value = "subject:*?0* OR content:*?0*", fields={"*","score"})
List<SomeDocument> find(String searchStr, Pageable pagebale);
```

Or use simply use `@Score` (currently only available for 1.4.RC1) within the document.

If you want to print out the query before execution please enable logging for `SolrTemplate` by adding `<logger name="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate" level="debug" />` to *logback.xml*.